# Need to repair connector for the Temp Sending connector on my Buick Nailhead engine

Tags: wiring, buick

I'm starting to work through the things that need doing on my 1965 Buick Wildcat.

At one time in the past, one or more rodents chewed through the wires on my Temperature Sending Unit.  I've replaced the unit and now I want to reconnect the wires.  Given the short length of the wire and the location of the damage I can't simply use butt connectors and move on, I will need to patch in some new wire.

Here are my potential solutions, in order of preference:

1. Find a source for a readymade pigtail.
2. Locate a new connector and wire to make my own pigtail.
3. Extract the blade contacts from the old connector and crimp new contacts onto new wires to make my own pigtail.

[image: Temperature Sending Connector]
Is anyone aware of a source for this part?

Alternately, can anyone tell me the right way to extract the blades from inside the connector without breaking it?

The engine is a 401cid Nailhead which uses a 2-wire sender (one for Cold, one for Hot) via a 90-degree connector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not finding the part you're looking for, so I bet it'd be a tough replacement.

Looking at it, there are a couple of options for you. First, you can buy  two *single* sided connectors, [like this](https://www.carpartsdiscount.com/catalog/buick~wildcat~65.html?3593=318855):

[image]

Using two of them, you can place it onto your sensor and connect it to the existing wiring harness.

You could always dismantle these by taking the contacts out of them and putting them into the body of your original plug. I believe if you use a very thin flat-tipped screwdriver, you can get the contact to release inside the body. Slide it up between the body and the contact all the way to the base and I'm pretty sure it will release. I'm not sure which side of the contact you'd need to work on, or which way it would come out (the wire side or the connector side), but the thing has to go together *somehow*, which means it will come apart. I believe I've done this before to the same time of connection (IIRC, I had a melted connector and took the wires out). Just play with it some and you can probably work it out without too much of a hassle.

An even easier fix may be to just get some female bladed terminal ends which would slide down onto the blades of the sensor. Connect these to your wires and you're in business.

**EDIT:** FOUND IT!

[PN:34621   TEMPERATURE SENDING UNIT LEAD REPAIR KIT, for 2 flat blade terminal type sending units](http://www.lectriclimited.com/mainpage.htm)

You'll have to drill down a bit to find it from the page. They have some markup on the page which shows as you click, but doesn't do anything with the URL. How you want to drill down in the catalog is as follows:

- Click on **Automotive Switches** from the main page
- Click on **View Catalog / Order Online** under any of the subsections
- Click on **Make/Model/Year of Vehicle**
- Click on **GM OLDSMOBILE FULLSIZE**
- Enter year, then click **Display Catalog**
- Scroll down to find the subsection entitled **REPAIR COMPONENTS (for wire harnesses)**

The part is listed there as shown above. As of this post, price is $17 (plus shipping I assume). Here is a picture of what you get:

[image]

Comment: @Paulster2 My Google-Fu is usually pretty good but this is buried pretty deep within their website.  How the heck did you find it?

Comment: @WildcatMatt - Google-Fu is strong with this one, young Padewan. :o) J/K! Sheer luck and a little digging.

Comment: @WildcatMatt - I'm surprised someone didn't shut this question down though ... it's mainly a shopping question. I don't think anyone would begrudge you this, though. Parts for old cars are hard to find most of the time.

Comment: As a follow-up, the same part is available when selecting GM BUICK FULLSIZE/RIVIERA.

Comment: @WildcatMatt - Yes, you'll find back then GM used the same parts across many different lines over many different years --- If it works, why re-engineer it?